# Track keyboard entries for matching strings

Tags: windows, keyboard, data-entry

Is there a software that can alert when immediately when I have keyed a specific number on my keyboard. See I work in a data entry environment and I have a series of reference numbers that are blacklisted, for example 123456789, 789456132, and so on. I need an application that will automatically alert me when I have stroked any number from a provided list.

I use Windows 7 and the applications that I am using do not provide this facility. I don't want to have to go to excel all the time to do a lookup. I need something that will run silently in the background and will only alert me when needs be.

Thanks in advance.